# I am getting this error ---> TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Tags: python, opencv, gesture-recognition

this a simple gesture recognition using python , opencv 
Libraries In Use
we will be using only 2 libraries in this tutorial

OpenCV
Numpy
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
    import wx
    mouse=Controller()

```
app=wx.App(False)
(sx,sy)=wx.GetDisplaySize()
(camx,camy)=(320,240)

lowerBound=np.array([33,80,40])
upperBound=np.array([102,255,255])

cam= cv2.VideoCapture(0)

kernelOpen=np.ones((5,5))
kernelClose=np.ones((20,20))
pinchFlag=0

while True:
ret, img=cam.read()
img=cv2.resize(img,(340,220))

#convert BGR to HSV
imgHSV= cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# create the Mask
mask=cv2.inRange(imgHSV,lowerBound,upperBound)
#morphology
maskOpen=cv2.morphologyEx(mask,cv2.MORPH_OPEN,kernelOpen)
maskClose=cv2.morphologyEx(maskOpen,cv2.MORPH_CLOSE,kernelClose)

maskFinal=maskClose
result = cv2.findContours(maskFinal.copy(), cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
conts,h=result if len(result) == 2 else result[1:3]

if(len(conts)==2):
    if(pinchFlag==1):
        pinchFlag=0
        mouse.release(Button.left)
    x1,y1,w1,h1=cv2.boundingRect(conts[0])
    x2,y2,w2,h2=cv2.boundingRect(conts[1])
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x1,y1),(x1+w1,y1+h1),(255,0,0),2)
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x2,y2),(x2+w2,y2+h2),(255,0,0),2)
    cx1=x1+w1/2
    cy1=y1+h1/2
    cx2=x2+w2/2
    cy2=y2+h2/2
    cx=(cx1+cx2)/2
    cy=(cy1+cy2)/2
    cv2.line(img, (cx1,cy1),(cx2,cy2),(255,0,0),2)
    cv2.circle(img, (cx,cy),2,(0,0,255),2)
    mouseLoc=(sx-(cx*sx/camx), cy*sy/camy)
    mouse.position=mouseLoc 
    while mouse.position!=mouseLoc:
        pass
elif(len(conts)==1):
    x,y,w,h=cv2.boundingRect(conts[0])
    if(pinchFlag==0):
        pinchFlag=1
        mouse.press(Button.left)
    cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
    cx=x+w/2
    cy=y+h/2
    cv2.circle(img,(cx,cy),(w+h)/4,(0,0,255),2)
    mouseLoc=(sx-(cx*sx/camx), cy*sy/camy)
    mouse.position=mouseLoc 
    while mouse.position!=mouseLoc:
        pass
cv2.imshow("cam",img)
cv2.waitKey(5)
Python
```

i get this error :- 
cv2.line(img, (cx1,cy1),(cx2,cy2),(255,0,0),2). 
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Answer (score 0):

`cv2.line` expects the values of coordinates to be integers, i.e. the value of cx1, cx2, cy1, cy2 should be integers. So before writing this statement write `cx1 = int(cx1)` and so on for others and the code should run.